# Create Table syntax error in sql Jupyter notebook

Tags: sql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I tried to create a table in sql. But I keep getting a syntax error. I tried the solutions from other answers on this website. But, I keep getting the syntax error. This is the code that I tried.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  StudentID int  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Major ARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
```

This is the error that I get.

```
File "<ipython-input-12-dff73a7a002a>", line 1
    CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running this on Jupyter notebook. Could anyone help me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small typo in your `CREATE` statement as below. You are missing `V`

```
  Major ARCHAR(20),
```

should be

```
Major VARCHAR(20),
```

Comment: In SQLite, this does not make any difference. (For determining the [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), only the "CHAR" substring matters.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try to run SQL-code with python kernel. But it isn't the way that would work. 
If you really want to execute SQL with Jupyter you should look at `ipython-sql` extension: https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

So at first install extension with `pip install ipython-sql`.
Then in a notebook load it with `%load_ext sql`.
And in the end, try your code, preliminarily it with `%%sql`-magic. I.e.:

```
%%sql sqlite://
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  StudentID int  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Major ARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
```

If my answer is off topic, just give me more information about what you do.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. It still gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @therealdev could you please show all the code or provide a screenshot? Because your code as it present in my answer works for me.

Comment: @therealdev I'm glad to hear! If so could you accept my answer as correct?

Comment: Note that ipython-sql is considered a legacy project (check out the readme), you can use JupySQL for this: https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql